# JTree nullpointer loading first row

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtree, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to select the first row on a JTree when i create it.
But sometimes i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.completeEditing(BasicTreeUI.java:2035)
   at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.valueChanged(BasicTreeUI.java:3715)
   at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:634)
   at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:1092)
   at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:293)
   at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPaths(JTree.java:1644)
   at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionRows(JTree.java:1721)
   at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionRow(JTree.java:1696)
```

before calling the tree.setSelectionRow(0) i try to put the following check without any effect:

```
    while((!tabTree.isVisible()) || (tabTree.isEditing()) || (tabTree.getRowCount() == 0)) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    tabTree.setSelectionRow(0);
```

You need to be saved :)

any suggestions?

Comment: Sometimes? See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: isn't that JTreeTable, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame, JTree and with hardcoded value for JTree (as local variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be caused by:

- You're using a custom cell editor which returns `null` in `getTreeCellEditorComponent()`
- You modify the tree in a non-UI thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: In fact, of all the standard JComponents, I've found JTree to be the most prone to erratic behavior when its methods are called, or its model modified, outside of the AWT event dispatch thread.

Comment: Following the guide you post i see that i call the setSelectionRow from another Thread. Now i try to put an invokeLater into that method to separate the thread. Thanks a lot